# disabling/enabling sidebar from server side

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

Is there any way to manually disabling/enabling the sidebar on shiny dashboard app from the server side?

I would like to hide the sidebar automatically when I need more space without using toggle button on the header.

Thank you

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with dashboards as I never built one, but from a taking a quick look, it seems like when clicking on the open/hide sidebar button, all that happens is a `sidebar-collapse` class gets added/removed to the `<body>` tag.  Maybe more things happen that I'm unaware of, but that seemed to be the most visible thing.

So you can easily use [shinyjs](http://deanattali.com/shinyjs/) package (disclaimer: I'm the author) to add/remove that class

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(
  ui = 
    dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(),
      dashboardSidebar(),
      dashboardBody(
        shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
        actionButton("showSidebar", "Show sidebar"),
        actionButton("hideSidebar", "Hide sidebar")
      )
    ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$showSidebar, {
      shinyjs::removeClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")
    })
    observeEvent(input$hideSidebar, {
      shinyjs::addClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: By the way, I'm using your library (shinyjs) since the first release. It is very useful for someone like me with a very basic experience with JS. I really like your approach for the library and actually I have learned a lot from the source code. So, thank you very much for creating shinyjs :)

Comment: how would you adjust the location of `useShinyjs()` the selector variables if your `dashboardBody` is rendered dynamically?