# Hide sidebar in default in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I used `shinydashboard` to create my app. I would like to hide the sidedar in default on desktop environment (e.g. windows), but not to disable it. On the mobile device, the sidebar is hide in default. I think I need to change the css class, but don't know how to do it.

Thanks for any suggestions.

This is my playing codes:

```
library(shiny)

library(shinydashboard)
ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody()
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: @NicE Thanks. I only want to hide the sidebar, not to disable it.

Comment: dashboardSidebar also now has an argument collapsed. If True, the sidebar will be collapsed by default.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is very similar to my answer from another SO thread: ["disabling/enabling sidebar from server side"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305930/disabling-enabling-sidebar-from-server-side/31306707#31306707)

Here's code that can do what you want by hiding the sidebar when the app starts (using the package shinyjs)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs()
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  addClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks. I find your answer, but Rstudio give me a warning message (argument "id" is missing and with no default). So I guess a id should be passed into addClass funcion.

Comment: Nope,  you shouldn't need to pass an id argument. If you copy this exact code you'll see that it just works and there's no error. Perhaps you're doing something else weird

Comment: It do work for me. Just see an warning message in RStudio.

Comment: If the exact code above is giving you a warning, maybe you have an old version of shinyjs or shiny. It should run without any problems at all

Comment: I've posted a follow up question about this linked with mouse hover here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44899706/display-sidebar-menu-on-hover-against-left-screen-wall

Comment: This is how we can `un-hide` the sidebar programatically. Thanks Dean!     `shinyjs::runjs("$('.sidebar-toggle').click();")`

Answer (score 40):

if you do a `?dashboardSidebar` you probably see the usage, like this

> dashboardSidebar(..., disable = FALSE, width = NULL, collapsed =
>   FALSE)

So this should work

```
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  collapsed = TRUE,
  sidebarMenu()
)
```

i'm not sure if this depends on your shinydashboard version but you could check/change that as well.

Comment: This works wonderfully! Is there also a way to disable the sidebar toggle?

Answer (score 2):

Add

dashboardSidebar(collapsed = TRUE)

instead of

dashboardSidebar()

in UI page.

Answer (score 1):

Or simply

```
ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(collapsed = TRUE),
  dashboardBody()
))
```

Comment: Thanks iLona. Would you know the command to `un-collapse`  the sidebar when called?