# How to collapse sidebarPanel in shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I have a shiny app with a mainPanel and a sidebarPanel inside a tabPanel in a navbarPage. I need an option to hide the sidebarPanel similar to this: [Hide sidebar in default in shinydashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35170065/hide-sidebar-in-default-in-shinydashboard) and https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs/issues/43.

An actionButton should control if the sidebarPanel is shown or collapsed.

This is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("",
             tabPanel("tab",
                      sidebarPanel(
                        useShinyjs()
                      ),
                  
                      mainPanel(actionButton("showSidebar", "Show sidebar"),
                                actionButton("hideSidebar", "Hide sidebar")
                      )
             )
  )
)

server <-function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$showSidebar, {
    shinyjs::removeClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebarPanel-collapse")
  })
  observeEvent(input$hideSidebar, {
    shinyjs::addClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebarPanel-collapse")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You almost got it right. `class` should be `sidebar-collapse` instead of `sidebarPanel-collapse`. HTH

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have modified your code to hide and show the sidebar. To create the `id` for the `sidebarPanel`I have enclosed it within div and given it the`id = Sidebar`. To show and hide the side bar I have used `shinyjs` function `show` and `hide` with the id as `Sidebar`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  navbarPage("",
             tabPanel("tab",
                      div( id ="Sidebar",sidebarPanel(
                      )),
                      
                      
                      mainPanel(actionButton("showSidebar", "Show sidebar"),
                                actionButton("hideSidebar", "Hide sidebar")
                      )
             )
  )
)

server <-function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$showSidebar, {
    shinyjs::show(id = "Sidebar")
  })
  observeEvent(input$hideSidebar, {
    shinyjs::hide(id = "Sidebar")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: nice answer, thanks (+1), but it might be better to use `shinyjs::toggle` with only one button

Comment: Yes that would definitely be a better option. The answer was  just inline withe question asked and the code that was provided. I'll definitely edit my answer with your suggestion very soon.

Answer (score 5):

An example of the toggle option suggested in previous comments.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  navbarPage("",
             tabPanel("tab",
                      div( id ="Sidebar",sidebarPanel(
                      )),


                      mainPanel(actionButton("toggleSidebar", "Toggle sidebar")
                      )
             )
  )
)

server <-function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$toggleSidebar, {
    shinyjs::toggle(id = "Sidebar")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3):

I made an example with toggle button on navbar and multiple tabs.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  navbarPage(title = tagList("title",actionLink("sidebar_button","",icon = icon("bars"))),
             id = "navbarID",
             tabPanel("tab1",
                      div(class="sidebar"
                          ,sidebarPanel("sidebar1")
                      ),
                      mainPanel(
                        "MainPanel1"
                      )
             ),
             tabPanel("tab2",
                      div(class="sidebar"
                          ,sidebarPanel("sidebar2")
                      ),
                      mainPanel(
                        "MainPanel2"
                      )
             )
  )
)

server <-function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$sidebar_button,{
    shinyjs::toggle(selector = ".sidebar")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

=======================================

I have created a simpler example that does not use the sidepanel class, but I am not sure if it will work in all environments.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  navbarPage(title = tagList("title",actionLink("sidebar_button","",icon = icon("bars"))),
             tabPanel("tab1",
                      sidebarPanel("sidebar1"),
                      mainPanel("MainPanel1")
             ),
             tabPanel("tab2",
                      sidebarPanel("sidebar2"),
                      mainPanel("MainPanel2")
             )
  )
)

server <-function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$sidebar_button,{
    shinyjs::toggle(selector = ".tab-pane.active div:has(> [role='complementary'])")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

=======================================

I've finally finished my collapsible sidebarpanel, and shinyjs runjs allows you to extend the width of the mainpanel when the sidebarpanel is collapsed.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  navbarPage(title = tagList("title",actionLink("sidebar_button","",icon = icon("bars"))),
             tabPanel("tab1",
                      sidebarPanel("sidebar1",width=3),
                      mainPanel("MainPanel1",width=9,style="background-color:gray")
             ),
             tabPanel("tab2",
                        sidebarPanel("sidebar2",width=5)
                        ,mainPanel("MainPanel2",width=7,style="background-color:gray")
             )
  )
)

server <-function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$sidebar_button,{
    shinyjs::toggle(selector = ".tab-pane.active div:has(> [role='complementary'])")
    
    js_maintab <- paste0('$(".tab-pane.active div[role=',"'main'",']")')
    
    runjs(paste0('
          width_percent = parseFloat(',js_maintab,'.css("width")) / parseFloat(',js_maintab,'.parent().css("width"));
          if (width_percent == 1){
            ',js_maintab,'.css("width","");
          } else {
            ',js_maintab,'.css("width","100%");
          }
          '))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I was able to create an example that works well, but there is one problem: hiding the sidebarPanel does not extend the width of the mainPanel to full screen. Hiding the sidebarPanel doesn't make the mainPanel any wider, so there's less point in hiding it. Do I still have to use the shinydashboard?

Comment: I've finally finished my collapsible sidebarpanel, and shinyjs runjs allows you to extend the width of the mainpanel when the sidebarpanel is collapsed.　Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

automatically collapse the sidebarPanel `shinyjs::runjs("$('.sidebar-toggle').click();")`

Comment: Where to put this ?

Comment: In a reactive or observer whenever you want the action to happen.

Comment: could even put it inside a `render` operation, which is what I did. When the app opens I want the user to login, nothing else is seen and the sidebarPanel is collapsed. Then after a successful login, the LDAP credentials of the user with their thumbnail photo are displayed, and sidebar toggle click to display.