# shiny - collapse sidebar while using appendTab

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I try to collapse the sidebar in the new tab once one of the marker in the example is clicked. Sidebar should stay in Main Dashboard tab

Little example app with data

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(shinydashboard)
library(purrr)
library(shinyjs)

pts <- data.frame(
  id= letters[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )],
  x = rnorm(10, mean = -93.625), 
  y = rnorm(10, mean = 42.0285))
```

ui part with `id="Sidebar"` for the sidebar element which should be hidden and `useShinyjs()`

```
ui <- dashboardPage(      
  dashboardHeader(title = "Test"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id="Sidebar",
                actionLink("remove", "Remove detail tabs"))),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(), # not really sure where this has to go?
    tabsetPanel(
    id = "tabs",
    tabPanel(
      title = "Main Dashboard",
      value = "page1",
      fluidRow(tabsetPanel(id='my_tabsetPanel',
                               tabPanel('Map1',
                                        leafletOutput('map1')   
                               )))))))
```

server part where I add an `Eventobserver()` within the `appendTab` which should recognize that a new tab is opened and hide the sidebar

```
###server   
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  tab_list <- NULL

  output$map1 <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      setView(-93.65, 42.0285, zoom = 6)
  })
  observe({        
    input$my_tabsetPanel        
    tab1 <- leafletProxy('map1', data = pts) %>%
      clearMarkers() %>% 
      addCircleMarkers(lng = ~x, lat = ~y, radius = 4, layerId = ~id)})

  observeEvent(input$map1_marker_click, { 
    clickedMarker <- input$map1_marker_click[1]
    tab_title <- paste(clickedMarker)   
    appendTab(inputId = "my_tabsetPanel",
              tabPanel(
                tab_title,
                fluidRow(                      
                  box('test')
                )))
    tab_list <<- c(tab_list, tab_title) 

    observeEvent(input$tabs == "my_tabsetPanel", { #also not sure if this is at the right place?
        shinyjs::hide(id = "Sidebar")
      })
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "my_tabsetPanel", selected = tab_title)       
  })

  observeEvent(input$remove,{
    tab_list %>%
      walk(~removeTab("my_tabsetPanel", .x))
    tab_list <<- NULL
  })}  

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Link to [similar but different problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830553/r-shiny-automatically-hide-the-sidebar-when-you-navigate-into-tab-items)!