# closing sidebar in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to make a multipage shiny dashboard.  I would like the sidebar to collapse when you pick a page, with the ability to reopen it to pick a new page.  For example, when you pick page 2 the sidebar collapses and you can reopen it later if you want to go back to page 1. Right now it is stuck open, i.e. when you click page 2 the sidebar does not collapse.  I used useShinyjs(), which is what I thought makes it collapsible with no luck.  Any help is much appreciated :)

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyBS)
library(plotly)

Stores <- data.frame(Store = c("Store 1", "Store 2", "Store 3", "Store 4", "Store 5"),
                     Sales = c(8247930, 423094, 204829, 903982, 7489472, 429085, 208955, 7492852, 5285034, 2958275,1598753, 28487593, 4892049, 583042, 509275, 5904728, 5098325, 5920947, 4920946, 2049583),
                     Avg_cust = c(325,542,582,482,904, 594, 304, 493, 690, 403, 694, 104, 493, 596, 403, 506, 304, 305, 632, 478),
                     Year = c(rep(2012,5), rep(2013,5), rep(2014,5), rep(2015,5)))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(
    title = "Store Performance",
    titleWidth = "100%"),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    useShinyjs(),
    width = 200,
    collapsed = FALSE,
    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                menuItem("Page 1", tabName = "pg1"),
                menuItem("Page 2", tabName = "pg2"))),
  skin = "black",
  body = dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    tabItems(
      tabItem("pg1",
              fluidRow(
                column(width = 3,
                       box(
                         title = "Options",
                         status = 'warning',
                         solidHeader = TRUE,
                         width = 12,
                         collapsible = FALSE,
                         collapsed = FALSE,
                         pickerInput(
                           inputId = "YR",
                           label = "Year:",
                           choices = c(2012,2013,2014,2015),
                           selected = 2015,
                           multiple = FALSE))),
                column(width = 9,
                       boxPlus(plotlyOutput("All"),
                               status = 'warning',
                               width = 12,
                               solidHeader = TRUE,
                               collapsible = FALSE,
                               closable = FALSE,
                               collapsed = FALSE)))),
      tabItem("pg2",
              fluidRow(
                column(width = 9,
                       boxPlus(title = "Add graph here",
                               width = 12,
                               status = "warning",
                               solidHeader = TRUE,
                               collapsible = FALSE,
                               closable = FALSE,
                               collapsed = FALSE)),
                column(width = 3,
                       box(
                         title = "Options",
                         status = 'warning',
                         solidHeader = TRUE,
                         width = 12,
                         collapsible = FALSE,
                         collapsed = FALSE,
                         pickerInput(
                           inputId = "st",
                           label = "Store:",
                           choices = unique(Stores$Store),
                           selected = "Store 1",
                           multiple = FALSE
                         ))))))))

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent({
    input$YR
  },
  
  output$All <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(Stores[Stores$Year == input$YR,], x = ~Avg_cust, y = ~Sales,
            hoverinfo = "text", text = ~Store)%>%
      layout(title = "Store Performance",
             xaxis = list(title = "Customers"),
             yaxis = list(title = "Sales"))
  })
  )
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only using `useShinyjs()` doesn't do the trick. It only sets up shinyjs, but you need to tell it what to do. The idea here is to add the class "sidebar-collapse" to the body, as this hides the sidebar. The sidebar should always been hidden if a tab was switched, so have to add an observer that listens if a tab was switched. Then you can use shinyjs to add the class with `addClass`. The input of the tabswitch is the id of the `sidebarMenu`:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyBS)
library(plotly)

Stores <- data.frame(Store = c("Store 1", "Store 2", "Store 3", "Store 4", "Store 5"),
                     Sales = c(8247930, 423094, 204829, 903982, 7489472, 429085, 208955, 7492852, 5285034, 2958275,1598753, 28487593, 4892049, 583042, 509275, 5904728, 5098325, 5920947, 4920946, 2049583),
                     Avg_cust = c(325,542,582,482,904, 594, 304, 493, 690, 403, 694, 104, 493, 596, 403, 506, 304, 305, 632, 478),
                     Year = c(rep(2012,5), rep(2013,5), rep(2014,5), rep(2015,5)))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(
    title = "Store Performance"),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    width = 200,
    collapsed = FALSE,
    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                menuItem("Page 1", tabName = "pg1"),
                menuItem("Page 2", tabName = "pg2"))),
  skin = "black",
  body = dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    tabItems(
      tabItem("pg1",
              fluidRow(
                column(width = 3,
                       box(
                         title = "Options",
                         status = 'warning',
                         solidHeader = TRUE,
                         width = 12,
                         collapsible = FALSE,
                         collapsed = FALSE,
                         pickerInput(
                           inputId = "YR",
                           label = "Year:",
                           choices = c(2012,2013,2014,2015),
                           selected = 2015,
                           multiple = FALSE))),
                column(width = 9,
                       box(plotlyOutput("All"),
                               status = 'warning',
                               width = 12,
                               solidHeader = TRUE,
                               collapsible = FALSE,
                               closable = FALSE,
                               collapsed = FALSE)))),
      tabItem("pg2",
              fluidRow(
                column(width = 9,
                       box(title = "Add graph here",
                               width = 12,
                               status = "warning",
                               solidHeader = TRUE,
                               collapsible = FALSE,
                               closable = FALSE,
                               collapsed = FALSE)),
                column(width = 3,
                       box(
                         title = "Options",
                         status = 'warning',
                         solidHeader = TRUE,
                         width = 12,
                         collapsible = FALSE,
                         collapsed = FALSE,
                         pickerInput(
                           inputId = "st",
                           label = "Store:",
                           choices = unique(Stores$Store),
                           selected = "Store 1",
                           multiple = FALSE
                         ))))))))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$All <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(Stores[Stores$Year == input$YR,], x = ~Avg_cust, y = ~Sales,
            hoverinfo = "text", text = ~Store)%>%
      layout(title = "Store Performance",
             xaxis = list(title = "Customers"),
             yaxis = list(title = "Sales"))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$tabs, {
    addClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")
  })
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

BTW: you also need the package `shinydashboardPlus`. Also, I removed your observer because I don't know what you want to achieve. Lastly, I reduced the width of the header, because otherwise the button to show the sidebar is hidden.

For more information how it works, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305930/disabling-enabling-sidebar-from-server-side/31306707#31306707) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830553/r-shiny-automatically-hide-the-sidebar-when-you-navigate-into-tab-items).